# Using non-participants as an excuse or justification to prohibit something

Tags: single-word-requests

So you often hear excuses or justifications to ban something to "protect children", e.g.

> We should ban pornography in order to protect children

Is there a word that describes this sort of justification or is it some sort of fallacy (the specific fallacy would also help).

Comment: Prohibit *something* as preventive care.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this? Are you thinking of the idiom *don't cut off your nose to spite your face* or, alternatively, *don't throw out the baby with the bath water*? Both of which are examples of expressions that argue against drawing conclusions that are too broad.

Comment: @JasonBassford No, I don't see how those two are related. My sentence is about justification, not drawing conclusions.

Comment: But a conclusion only *can* be drawn through justification—and can only be accepted by the other party, if they think it's sound. To rephrase, *you should cut off your nose in order to make your face even* or *you should throw out the baby in order to drain the dirty water*. I don't see how either of those is intrinsically different than the sentence you provided: *you should x in order to y*. As far as I can tell, you're saying that the evidence for the conclusion isn't sufficiently compelling—so, the otherwise too-broad conclusion isn't justified . . .

Comment: In other words, *I should drink in order to stop my thirst* is fine because the conclusion isn't broad *and* the justification for it is sufficient to address it.

Comment: @JasonBassford Why do you make it sound as though that a conclusion and justification are the same thing? If I say: "The sky is blue, therefore I will win the lottery today" is somehow a case of "throwing out the baby with the bath water"?

Comment: 'Protecting the helpless/defenceless' is surely an undeniable moral duty. Taken too far, it's known as 'nannying'.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to underline   the injustice of this action, it's **BIAS**.

***BIAS***

1a: an inclination of temperament or outlook

especially

: a personal and sometimes unreasoned judgment 
: PREJUDICE

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bias)